# Function to space out comments evenly in linux

Tags: linux

Hi I am writing a custom function in linux that is designed to put four spaces after a comment indicator.  I am unfamiliar with writing code in linux, I am more proficient in reading it rather than writing it out.  the comments are signified with the ";" character. So far this is what I have in the draft.  This is basic linux using putty for a bash emulator.

```
commentPlacer()
{

typeset -i count1=0  #iterator for first loop
typeset -i count2=0  #iterator for secod loop
len= ${#$1}  #length of argumnent
comment=";"
space= " "
comIndex=${$1#/;/}  #index of the comment
commentSpace= ";    "  #the comment indicator with the proper spacing

for(( count1; count1 <= len; count1++ ))  #loop to check if there is a comment on the line
    if [[ $1[count] == comment ]]
        for (( count2; count2 < $1[count1]; count2++ ))
                if [[ $1[count2] != commentSpace  ]]  #if the line doesn't have enough spacing in the comment use commentSpace variable 
                    then echo ${{$1:0:comIndex - 1} + commentSpace + {$1:commentSpace + 1: -1}} #cut off line before comment indicator and replace the line with the proper spacing.
                fi
        done
    fi
done
}
```

The code is meant to iterate through and argument, check to see if there is a `;` in the line and if there is it will put four spaces before the ';' to indicate the comment.  The error I get is that the 'fi' on line 17 of the code is a syntax error.  Again I'm more of a javascript coder, if someone could give me a point in right direction I would greatly appreciate it I am in the process of learning linux.  The results should take the following code:

```
commentPlacer x="example" ;This line is a comment.
```

Reformatting it to look like this:

```
x="example"    ;This line is a comment.
```

Comment: comment for which language? You might use some indenter like [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) or [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). BTW you don't show any [MCVE]. So please **edit your question** to improve it. Also, most [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor)s, such as [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), can indent code

Comment: I have done as you asked thank you for your time.

Comment: Even with the edit, you don't give any [MCVE] and you don't really explain the syntax of the language you want to pretty print

Comment: Forgive me this is literally my first function in linux.  I literally have no idea what I'm doing sorry for frustrating you.

Comment: The [MCVE] requirement is mandatory on StackOverflow (and unrelated to Linux). Whatever question you ask here, you need to provide readers with enough information and context to reproduce your problem on their machine

Comment: I will be sure to do so in the future, thank you so much for your time, I've learned a lot about linux just from you looking at my code I truly appreciate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell in which language is the incomplete code in your question coded in. I'm guessing it is [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or some other POSIX sh.

Then read carefully the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). You should at least code

```
for (( count1; count1 <= len; count1++ )) ; do
# more code here
done
```

and

```
if [[ $1[count] == comment ]]; then
# more code here
fi
```

But see also [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html); you might use `[ "$1[count]" -eq comment ]`

Of course, your `commentPlacer` shell function should be invoked properly, perhaps (using [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)) with

```
commentPlacer 'x="example"' ';This line is a comment'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in a `bash` shell script...

Both your `for` loops are missing `do`, and your first `if` statement is missing `then`.  Additionally, `bash` don't concatenate strings with `+`, some variable expansions seem to be missing `$`, and most of the expansions are unquoted. And you can't index into a string with `$varname[index]`.

The same thing could be done with `sed`:

```
sed 's/;[[:blank:]]*/;    /' file
```

If you really want to write this as a shell function, I strongly suggest that you follow proper development methods and test your code after each change.  You may also benefit from using the https://www.shellcheck.net/ site for checking the syntax of your code.

Comment: Thank you again this is my first foray into linux.  I'd rather learn how to write it properly rather than utilize a 'sed'.

Comment: @BrianMoore I'd argue that using the right tool for the job is to solve a problem "properly".

Comment: That being true @Kusalananda if you don't know how to use said tool or how it works how can you know which tool to use and when?

Comment: @BrianMoore Well, you ask a question (a good first step), and if you are willing to learn, you could try the suggestions given to you. There's no need to complicate things.

Comment: you are right, for right now I'm just glad I understand the syntax of if statements and for loops, I've got more questions but right now this was huge for me, thank you for your time and patience.